Error with AsyncSession object: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'add'
I'm using pytest for my FastAPI async project to assert connectivity to my database session. I am getting this error after poetry run pytest tests/test.py:

  async_session.add(test_record)


E       AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'add'
conftest.py:
import pytest
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from app.main import SignalAmplitude, DATABASE_URL, Base

engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
TestSessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
async def setup_database():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    yield
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)

@pytest.fixture
async def async_session():
    async with TestSessionLocal() as session:
        yield session`

test.py:
import pytest
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from app.main import app, SignalAmplitude
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

client = TestClient(app)

def test_health_check():
    response = client.get("/health_check")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"status": "ok"}

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_db_connectivity(async_session: AsyncSession):
    test_record = SignalAmplitude(amplitude=1.00, timestamp=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    async_session.add(test_record)
    await db_session.commit()

    result = await async_session.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM signal_amplitudes WHERE amplitude = :amplitude",
        {"amplitude": 1.00},
    )
    record = result.fetchone()

    assert record is not None
    assert record.amplitude == 1.00`


I was not able to use libraries like greenlet, for my environment would just show new errors.
I would appreciate any help on this.
